# Copying texts with same formating from word file to PowerPoint textbox using python

Tags: python, powerpoint, docx

I'm trying to copy texts from the word document into a PowerPoint text box using Python. I want all the texts in the word document in the exact same formatting into one PowerPoint text box. The problem here is some of the paragraphs are in bold and some are not. I'm not sure if this is even possible. Please see below how the word doc looks like:-

[Word Doc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnEkg.png)

And this is how it should look like in the ppt (In one text box)

[PowerPoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0AT0.png)

I'm using python docx and pptx library but I'm not expert in them. Please help!

Edit:

some of the things I've tried so far:-

I found one code to copy texts with styles but it is for word to word.

```py
def get_para_data(output_doc_name, paragraph):
    """
    Write the run to the new file and then set its font, bold, alignment, color etc. data.
    """

    output_para = output_doc_name.add_paragraph()
    for run in paragraph.runs:
        output_run = output_para.add_run(run.text)
        # Run's bold data
        output_run.bold = run.bold
        # Run's italic data
        output_run.italic = run.italic
        # Run's underline data
        output_run.underline = run.underline
        # Run's color data
        output_run.font.color.rgb = run.font.color.rgb
        # Run's font data
        output_run.style.name = run.style.name
    # Paragraph's alignment data
    output_para.paragraph_format.alignment = paragraph.paragraph_format.alignment
```

```py
input_doc = Document('InputDoc.docx')
output_doc = Document()

# Call the function
get_para_data(output_doc, input_doc.paragraphs[3])

# Save the new file
output_doc.save('OutputDoc.docx')
```

Please let me know how to do this from word to PowerPoint.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Edited the question. You can see things I've tried.